# How to do Xamarin.Forms authentication in ASP.Net Boilerplate with JwtBearer?

Tags: xamarin.forms, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

How can I authenticate the native Xamarin.Forms mobile application with ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Is there any library for Xamarin to authenticate with ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Could anyone post an example of how to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: hi, in aspnetboilerplate/module-zero repository there's angular login. you can check out the login mechanism there. it's a basic token based auth. you have to get the token and add it in header for every request.

Comment: check out https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/angular/src/account/login/login.component.ts